# process.env variables not the same value as in .env config

Tags: node.js, dotenv

In a recent nodejs project, I had a very strange occurrence: I set the HOSTNAME variable in my .env file, and by the time it got included in the .js file, the HOSTNAME value was different from the one in .env. **Why**?

--

### Situation

.env

```
HOSTNAME=foo.bar.com
```

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log("Hostname: ", process.env.HOSTNAME);
```

console output

```
Hostname: foo
```

**Expected console output**

```
Hostname: foo.bar.com
```

--

### Debugging

- Nodejs application is installed on a windows server 2008, where the machine's DNS entry is foo.bar.com. From the intranet, the machine is even reachable as "http://foo" (for whatever reason).
- No other nodejs application runs on that server
- Problem only occurs with HOSTNAME, no other variable name (at least not as far as I could find)
- works perfectly fine if HOSTNAME=localhost and I run the application from the server browser
- works perfectly fine if I rename HOSTNAME to _HOSTNAME (and replace all occurrences of HOSTNAME in my code)
- works perfectly fine if I run the code on my local machine and just have a .hosts entry "127.0.0.1 foo.bar.com"

I have fixed the issue by renaming to _HOSTNAME, but I would like to know WHY this happened, and if there are other .env variable names that might be affected by this strange occurrence

Comment: `HOSTNAME` probably already exists, existing env variables are not overwritten: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#what-happens-to-environment-variables-that-were-already-set

Comment: @RolandStarke Thank you very much for the hint; does dotenv (or nodejs) load some windows path variables or stuff like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dotenv` npm library skips the variables which already set in the host environment.You can find the more information about overriding existing system variables in official documentation.

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#what-happens-to-environment-variables-that-were-already-set